# Outputting less into a file

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

while on bash, i tried to delete the 3 last columns of a file using:

> head -n -3 file > file

but the file comes out empty. I can walkaround it but I would like to know what causes that.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: clarify: you want to remove columns as stated in the question or lines as used in `head` in your example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break down what that command does.

1. `> file`

   This opens `file` for writing, and truncates it.
2. `head -n -3 file`

   This reads all but the last 3 lines of `file`. **Yes, the same `file` you truncated in step 1.**

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is inline replacement, which isn't really possible without workarounds. In your command, the original file is overwritten because it's already opened and cleared when you send off the command.

Here are a couple of ideas:

- Use a temporary file

  ```
  head -n -3 file > tmp
  mv tmp file
  ```
- Use the [`sponge`](http://riva.ucam.org/~cjwatson/blog/2006/02/06#2006-02-06-sponge) tool from [`moreutils`](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/), which soaks up all input and then writes to the file:

  ```
  head -n -3 file | sponge file
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '-2,d|x' file
```

1. `-2,` select last 3 lines
2. `d` delete
3. `x` save and close